# simplexml_load_file() não reconhece urlldecode

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte **classe** para calculo de **distancias**:

```
<?php

class CalculaFrete {    

    # funcao de calculo da distãncia

    private function calculaDistancia(string $_cidade, string $_estado) : ?Array {

        $cidadeOrigem = 'Muriaé';
        $estadoOrigem = 'MG';

        $key = 'abcd...';

        $parametros = [
           'units'       =>'metric',
           'mode'        =>'driving',
           'origins'     => $cidadeOrigem . '-' . $estadoOrigem,
           'destinations'=> $_cidade . '-' . $_estado,
            'key'        => $key
        ];

        $urlDistancia = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?' . urldecode( http_build_query ( $parametros ) ) ;       

        $xml = simplexml_load_file( utf8_encode( $urlDistancia ) );

        $distancia = json_decode($xml);

        return $distancia->rows->elements->status == 'OK' ? $distancia->rows->elements : null;

    }

    # funcao de calculo de preços e prazos para serviços de transportadoras

    public function calculaFreteTransportadora(string $_cidade, string $_estado, float $_precoKM, float $_quantidade) : ?float {

        $distancia = $this->calculaDistancia( $_cidade, $_estado);

        return is_null( $distancia ) ? null : $distancia * $_precoKM * $_quantidade;

    }


}

$frete = new CalculaFrete();

echo $frete->calculaFreteTransportadora('Carangola','MG', 0.56, 5) ;
```

e a resposta de

```
echo $frete->calculaFreteTransportadora('Carangola','MG', 0.56, 5) ;
```

é:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=Muria%C3%83%C2%A9-MG&destinations=Carangola-MG&mode=driving&key=abcd...:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\util\CalculaFrete.php on line 73
```

Obs.: **abcd...** é uma **substituição** da `key` **verdadeira** para postagem aqui no fórum.

Onde estou errando?

parece que o problema está em:

```
Muria%C3%83%C2%A9
```

quando entra em

```
simplexml_load_file
```

Tentei de acordo com o que o colega disse mas o erro persiste:

```
$parametros = [
   'units'       =>'metric',
   'mode'        =>'driving',
   'origins'     => $cidadeOrigem . '-' . $estadoOrigem,
   'destinations'=> $_cidade . '-' . $_estado,
    'key'        => $key
];

$urlDistancia = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?' . http_build_query ( $parametros ) ;        

$xml = simplexml_load_file( $urlDistancia );

$distancia = json_decode($xml);
```

e segue o erro:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&mode=driving&origins=Muria%C3%A9-MG&destinations=Carangola-MG&key=AIzaSyC8LfR2NO9E-5w8-sCPVH-uVLo9FRUz6jc:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\util\CalculaFrete.php on line 73
```

Comment: Isso esta errado `urldecode( http_build_query ( $parametros ) )`, ou melhor é desnecessário. Como disse na outra resposta http_build_query não precisa de urlencode... E muito menos de utf8_encode --> `utf8_encode( $urlDistancia )`. Fazendo esses ajustes provavelmente irá corrigir a URL e irá funcionar.

Comment: fiz os ajuste e continuou o erro. Coloquei o ajuste no final da pergunta. Pode dar mais uma olhada fazendo favor? Obrigado! Warning: simplexml_load_file(): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&mode=driving&origins=Muria%C3%A9-MG&destinations=Carangola-MG&key=AIzaSyC8LfR2NO9E-5w8-sCPVH-uVLo9FRUz6jc:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\mvc_crud_pdo\classes\util\CalculaFrete.php on line 73

Comment: É porque esta URL não retorna um XML, retorna JSON. O simplexml_load_file não trabalha com JSON, até aonde sei. Recomendo que leia o erro SEMPRE, mesmo que em ingles, afinal sua tentantiva de usar urlencode e utf8_encode não tinha sentido para resolver este problema, tem que resolver o problema pedido pelo interpretador da linguagem ;)

Comment: Esta tentando Ler um arquivo Json como se fosse XML.
Se deseja fazer isso utilize cURL